# records from table where date between two years

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to get the record from one table where date between June-30-2011 and June-30-2012.
the problem is that the result is just only display the records of year 2012 although the table has records for year 2011. 
below is my code

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name where date between '06/30/2011' and '06/30/2012'
```

Comment: is the date column actually a datetime datatype? or string?

Comment: why use variable length string to store dates? but hey... what format are the "dates" stored in?

Comment: the same format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Did you realize that there is no 31st of June? ((c) by @gbn)

Comment: @dezso oh that sort of my mistake but dude its dummy date I am not using this anywhere

Comment: @Explosion Pills thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert it bact to `date` using `STR_TO_DATE`, eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
where STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') between '2011-06-31' and '2012-06-31'
```

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

It is not good to store `Dates` as string on database because as you see it is hard to search for it, you need some extra functions to convert it back to date and to which *I think* it kills the index.

If you have time or privilege to alter, fix the values and change it to `DateTime` data type.

Comment: yeah i have privileges but i don't need time as it has another column